# Create new table using calculated values in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sum, data-manipulation

Currently I'm involved in a data analysis project and my goal is to recreate a table filled with new (recalculated) indicators (old one is 10x10 filled with indicators, then I have to recalculate these indicators and insert new values into the same tabular form).

I'm using PySpark, and below you can find an example of my code:

```py
res2 = res1.withColumn("EAD", when((col("Debt") == 0) & (col("Result") > 360), col("Main_Debt")).otherwise(0))

res2.agg({"EAD": "sum"}).show()
```

I create new column based on filtering, then calculate the sum of this new column and ask PySpark to show the result.

Given the size of the code, I have to calculate approximately 100-130 sums, and it is a bit time-consuming to copy and paste the results.

How can I create a table and insert the values obtained into it?

Comment: you can do multiple aggregations within `agg()`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same result using `agg` aggregation which is more flexible.

Input example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

res1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(0, 350, 1),
     (0, 370, 1),
     (1, 350, 1),
     (1, 370, 1)],
    ['Debt', 'Result', 'Main_Debt'])
```

Script, equivalent to yours:

```py
res2 = res1.agg(
    F.sum(F.when((F.col("Debt") == 0) & (F.col("Result") > 360), F.col("Main_Debt")).otherwise(0)).alias("EAD")
)
res2.show()
# +---+
# |EAD|
# +---+
# |  1|
# +---+
```

You can also add more aggregations to it like this:

```py
res2 = res1.agg(
    F.sum(F.when((F.col("Debt") == 0) & (F.col("Result") > 360), F.col("Main_Debt")).otherwise(0)).alias("EAD"),
    F.sum('Main_Debt').alias('sum_main'),
    F.count(F.when(F.col('Debt') > 0, 1)).alias('cnt_debt')
)

res2.show()
# +---+--------+--------+
# |EAD|sum_main|cnt_debt|
# +---+--------+--------+
# |  1|       4|       2|
# +---+--------+--------+
```